# How do I make a TTreeView display a node when I select it?

Tags: delphi

If I have a TTreeView, and I call something like this:

```
myTreeView.Select(nodeIWantSelected);
```

it gets selected, but unless that node happens to be located within the part of the tree that's currently visible, I don't see it and I have to drag the scroll bar around until I find its position.  How can I make the TTreeView scroll to the node when I select it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use nodeIWantSelected.MakeVisible

Answer (score 1):

I can not test it right now but one of these might produce the desired effect:

```
myTreeView.Select(nodeIWantSelected);
myTreeView.Selected.MakeVisible;
// or
myTreeView.Selected.Focused := true;
```